# why alert not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i am designing a constructor function of an object type called Product that takes 3 parameters: aProdID, aDesc, and aPrice.
displays the product object details by using alert(). For example, the output alert window should show the following if a product object is created with “A001”, “Coke”, “6” for the product number, product description, and product price respectively.

```
function product(aProdID, aDesc,aPrice){
     var quantity=0
     this.aProdID=aProdID;
     this.aDesc=aDesc;
     this.aPrice=aPrice;
     return aProdID, aDesc,aPrice;
}
var product1= new product('A001','Coke',6)

alert(product1);
```

But it display [Object Object]
What's wrong with that? 
thanks a lot

Comment: You are alerting a JS object. You need to convert it to a string. alert(JSON.stringify(product1));

Comment: If you're doing this for debugging purposes, use `console.log()` it shows much more information and allows you to track object references. In Chrome, you can activate the console with `Ctrl + Shift + I`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `product1` is an object. When you call the `alert` passing `product1` as a parameter, the the `toString` method of the `product1` is called. Since you haven't overriden this method, you see the default output, which it `[Object object]`.

```js
function Product(aProdID, aDesc, aPrice){
     this.aProdID=aProdID;
     this.aDesc=aDesc;
     this.aPrice=aPrice;
}

Product.prototype.toString = function(){
    return 'ProductId: ' + this.aProdID + 'Desc: ' + this.aDesc + 'Price: '+ this.aPrice;
}

var product1= new Product('A001','Coke',6)

alert(product1);
```

**Side notes**

As you will notice I renamed he constructor function from `product` to `Product`. This is a very common convention in the JavaScript language, in order to notify the reader of you code that this function is a constructor function (one that can be used along with the new operator to create other objects).

Furthermore, I removed the return statement, since a constructor function should **not** have a return statement. Last but not least I deleted the local variable called `quantity`, since its not used anywhere.

Below you will find two very helpful links regarding this context:

- [The Constructor Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript)
- [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: thanks a lot . Your explanations are very clear. since i fully understand what you mean even though i study js soon.Especially revise my basic concept

Answer (score 0):

firstly you are using new to call the function and new always create object so the alert will be an object.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh same think happend to me then i found out that my information is be store in  as object so in your case

```
alert(product1.aProdID);
```

To get the "A001"